# Form post failing on PHP page

Tags: php, html

I have a simple signup form:

```
        <h2>Signup</h2>
        <form action="actions.php">
          Email:<br>
          <input type="text" name="lastname">
          <br>
          Password:<br>
          <input type="text" name="lastname">
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="submit" name="signupButton" value="submit">
        </form>
```

And here is my actions.php:

```
<?php
echo 'test1';

if(isset($_POST['signupButton'])){
    echo 'test2';
}
?>
```

But when I click the submit button the page that shows is only shows:

test1

Why is the button being clicked failing to pass the if statement?

Comment: did you try: `<form action="actions.php" method="post">` ?

Comment: the default form method is GET

Comment: @Fred-ii- ~ intriguing that it was re-opened when it does appear that it's clearly a mistook on the @ops behalf and I agree that the `$_POST` call doesn't match with the form default method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to specify a method type (post/get)

```
<form action="actions.php" method="POST">
```